# Syntax for converting expired weak_ptr<T> to shared_ptr<T>

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

From what I've read, a `shared_ptr<T>` does not get de-allocated until both strong references AND weak references to it are dropped.

I understand a shared object to be considered expired when there are no more strong references to it. The standard lock() function of a `weak_ptr<T>` therefore fails in such a case because the object is considered 'expired'.

However, if the deleter of a shared pointer is overridden such that the managed object is not deleted, then it should be valid to generated `shared_ptr<T>` from a `weak_ptr<T>` - but I cannot find the right syntax to do this.

```
std::shared_ptr<int> s_ptr(new(42), D());
std::weak_ptr<int) w_ptr(s_ptr);
s_ptr.reset();

s_ptr = std::shared_ptr<int>(w_ptr, false);
```

**EDIT**

To clarify this a bit further, I'm trying to construct an object pool of re-usable `shared_ptr<T>`. The reason behind this is because every use of shared_ptr results in one or more heap memory allocations. So I've added a deleter to every `shared_ptr<T>` which stores a `weak_ptr<T>` reference such that then the deleter gets called it should be able to re-add itself to a pool of available `shared_ptr<T>` objects (with managed object intact). By keeping a `weak_ptr<T>` stored inside the `shared_ptr<T>`'s deleter, it therefore shouldn't stop the deleter from being called.

The end goal is to obtain a smart pointer that doesn't do consisant heap allocation - or at least only a small number.

Comment: I don't think this kind of use is intended. Also, what makes you so sure that the pointer is preserved anywhere after it isn't needed any more? Just curious, what are you trying to solve with that? BTW: What exactly do you mean with your first sentence? What exactly is not being deallocated? It sounds ambiguous to me.

Comment: It sounds both pointless and dangerous to me, an XY problem. What is the actual objectives?

Comment: @Ulrich - By the first sentence I mean than the control block still exists are the strong pointer count reaches zero. Ref: "The control block does not deallocate itself until the std::weak_ptr counter reaches zero as well." from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr

Comment: @EJP, I'm trying to construct an object pool of shared_ptr. Not a pool of the managed objects, but a pool of shared_ptr's to the object. I am keeping a weak_ptr reference to any allocated shared_ptr to keep it alive for recycling.

Comment: I reason behind wanting an object pool of shared pointers is because I am creating a truck load of them - each existing for a short period of time. Therefore I was concerned about memory fragmentation. I figured creating an object pool of them should be easy...

Comment: Why doesn't the deleter return the object to the pool then?

Comment: @Ulrich, the deleter does return the object to the pool - or at least its trying to. The deleter function only gets a handle to the managed object itself - not the control block nor the shared_ptr itself. The deleter object cannot store a reference to the shared_ptr directly because that will result in a stronger reference and therefore the deleter will never be called. That is why I'm storing a weak_ptr inside the deleter.

Comment: The deleter is invoked to release the pointee from the ownership of last shared_ptr. Assuming the object was allocated with `new`, the default deleter thus uses `delete` to handle this. If you want, you can take the raw pointer (it ceased to be involved with any shared/weak pointer!) and store it in the pool again. How you store it inside the pool is up to you, I'd consider is using a `vector<unique_ptr<T>>`. When retrieving an element from the pool, you simply remove it from the vector and convert it to a `shared_ptr` with a proper deleter. Note that no reference is retained in the pool!

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, Yes, storing the raw pointers to T is one way to do this. However doing that will require converting the raw `T` point into a `shared_ptr` when the user requests a new shared_ptr<T> from the pool. Thus a new allocation on the heap for the control block. I was hoping that this control block allocation could be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

> From what I've read, a shared_ptr does not get de-allocated until both strong references AND weak references to it are dropped.

Wrong. a `std::shared_ptr` has two blocks - a control block that contains reference counts, etc, then another block for the actual data.

When the shared count goes to 0, the data block is (usually) deallocated. This is why it is illegal to make a `std::shared_ptr` from a expired `std::weak_ptr`.

On another note, why would you EVER want this functionality? It ruins the entire point of `std::weak_ptr`, which is to be able "store" a pointer to a object stored by `std::shared_ptr` without incrementing its reference count.
If you want to do that, then please just use a `std::shared_ptr`

Comment: I did mention that I was overriding the deleter function such that the managed object wasn't being deleted. The reason behind this usage is to pool the shared_ptrs for reuse.

Comment: true, sorry. Any reason you can't just use a contariner of `shared_ptr`s?

Comment: A container of shared_ptr's will then keep a strong reference to the managed object, and thus the use-count will never reach zero - therefore the deleter will not fire. (I'm using the deleter function to do the actual returning of the shared_ptr to the object pool)

Comment: Because this is kinda a hack, i think that a `weak_ptr` wont do what you want because that is exactly what `weak_ptr` is trying to prevent. In order to do what you want, then I suggest you just store a raw pointer to the object.

Comment: I absolutely agree with you - except for the fact that creating a shared_ptr from a raw pointer results in a heap allocation for the control block - which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: No, you could just cache one. use `make_shared` then use the `shared_ptr::get` function to store the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

If pooling control blocks is a good idea, the library implementation may *already* be doing it. In fact, the implementation of `new` itself may already be doing pooling to support similar memory usage patterns.

Furthermore, you can achieve what I think your goals are by using `make_shared` rather than invoking `new` and passing it into a `shared_ptr` constructor; one of the reasons for the existence of this helper function is that it can be written to use a *single* allocation to allocate both the control block *and* the new object you're creating at the same time.

Comment: The difficulty with using `make_shared` is that it doesn't allow for a custom deleter. I can find zero ways to use custom deleter logic with `make_shared`. Which means the managed object must be heap deleted.

Comment: Are you implying that one could construct and destruct shared_ptr's ad infinitum without concern of memory fragmentation because default memory allocator pool's control blocks constructed?